# Changing Default Expiry on a Dataset - How to ensure data preservation

Tags: google-bigquery

I have noticed that my big query database was configured to clear data more than 60 days old. The setting has been changed on the dataset for Default table expiry = Never but came with the warning "existing tables will not be affected"

What does this mean for future data preservation? It looks as though each day is its own table, so the 60 day expiry will only stop being a problem 60 days from now?

any clarification on what the wording of this warning means and how it will affect our data preservation in big query would be great

thanks

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created tables in that dataset, then these table still have 60 days expiry. You need to clear this setting on each table individually. Otherwise all data older than 60 days will keep deleting every day.

If your system creates new table everyday, then yes, the expiry will stop being a problem after 60 days, because new tables will have no expiry. All old tables will be emptied though.

Comment: Ah I was missing how to update for each table, now I see it it makes a lot of sense.